# php mod_rewrite cannot get second parameter from rewritecond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have a server that I am setting up to rewrite subdomains as get parameters

So, 
**subdomain.example.com/blog/test** 
would actually point to:
**example.com/index.php?website=subdomain&request=blog/test**

I have setup the domain with an A record with a value of *, and I have setup the server to ALIAS *.example.com to example.com. All of that is working.

In my .htaccess I have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/\.]+).example.com(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?website=%1&request=%2 [L]
```

Here is a var_dump() of $_GET when i go to subdomain.example.com/blog/test

```
array(2) { ["website"]=> string(8) "subdomain" ["request"]=> string(0) "" }
```

the subdomain is coming in perfectly in the website parameter, but the rest of the request is not there in the request parameter. Any Ideas? I really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

By the way if I use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?website=%1&request=$1 [L]
```

Then I get **index.php** in the request parameter. If that tells you something additional.

AMENDMENT

Per John's suggestion I tried the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/\.]+).wescms.com(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?website=%1&request=%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

If you go to **subdomain.example.com/blog/test** the REQUEST_URI comes back with index.php
I did a var_dump() of the $_SERVER variable, and in the REQUEST_URI it shows /blog/test, but its not making it through the RewriteRule.

If I use THE_REQUEST in the rewrite rule rather than REQUEST_URI, I get back what I need plus some extra bits but I would appreciate understanding more about why REQUEST_URI is not working as in my last example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `RewriteCond` is matching against `%{HTTP_HOST}`, which only includes the *hostname* the of the request, not the "path" portion.

The requested resource (basically, the part of the URL after the hostname) is available as the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable. In your situation, you could use the variable directly in your rule rather than trying to capture that data in a `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Hey John thanks for the quick response, I tried your suggestion and REQUEST_URI was coming back containing index.php. Not the path I need, I amended my question above with more details.